# AngularJS: timeout promise calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, timeout, promise

In my `AjaxPromiseService.js` factory, I have been trying to incorporate a timeout mechanism into promise calls (usually *$http.get/post* calls to remote services). The way I am currently doing is to create a race between a `$timeout` event and the actual promise calls. Example code as following (code from my `AjaxPromiseService.js` factory in AngularJS): [also available in this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/QMnEnwwaDuVWjtmE0Ryi?p=info)

```
var timeoutObj = {"isTimeout": true};

function timeoutPromise(deferredObj) {
      $timeout(function() {
        console.log("promise timeout");
        deferredObj.resolve(timeoutObj);
        }, timeoutLimit); // timeoutLimit is in milisecond
    }

//promise calls (e.g. $http.get())
function getDummyData(milisec) {
      var data = {"data" : "dummy data from ajax!"};
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      timeoutPromise(deferred); //start the race to see who resolves first

      //use $timeout to mimick an AJAX call
      $timeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve(data);
        $timeout.cancel(timeoutPromise(deferred)); //not working, how to cancel the race here?
      }, milisec); //

      return deferred.promise;

    } //getDummyData
```

This seems working, if `getDummyData()` is not resolved within the specified duration, the `timeoutPromise()` will return the useful flag so I can let the AJAX calls fail gracefully. Both `timeoutPromise()` and `getDummyData()` will resolve eventually in a sequential order, however, I would like to **cancel** `timeoutPromise()` if `getDummyData()` is reslolved first. I was wondering how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$http` has a `timeout` parameter, which times out the request when a promise is resolved - so, you could give it a `$timeout` promise:

```
getData: function(input, timeout){
  var timeoutPromise = timeout ? $timeout(function(){}, timeout) : null;

  return $http({url: "/some/url",
                timeout: timeoutPromise,
                method: "GET"
               }).then(function(response){
                  var data = response.data;
                  // do something with data, if needed
                  return data;
               });
}
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/NggPyhQXAWN8bB8t4ASX?p=preview)**

Comment: `return $http().then()` returns a promise... I'm not sure what you're asking otherwise  - a promise of what?

Comment: so you don't need to wrap $q.defer() in $http() to return a promise?

Comment: @TonyGW, one rarely does when the function itself returns a promise, like `$http` and `$timeout` do... in fact, it would be a [deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern)

Comment: but in the timeoutPromise, if I want to return a promise object that has a flag {isTimeout: true}, do I need $q to create a promise for return?

Comment: `timeoutPromise` in your question or in my answer? do you mean to return it to the user of `getData`? Where is it going to be used - in the promise handler or by the caller? In other words, I don't fully understand your new requirement. I suggest you either edit your question with clarification or create a new question

Answer (score 1):

If you're using $http, there is a much simpler option. Use timeout property of $http configuration object, and $timeout service:

```
var requestTimeout = $timeout(function() {}, 4000);
$http({ method:'GET', url:'...', timeout: requestTimeout});
requestTimeout.then(function() {
   console.log ('request aborted - timed out!');
});
```

The $timeout will automatically be aborted when the request succeeds within the timeout period.

Answer (score 1):

According to **[$http documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)**, the `timeout` property of the *$http configuration* accepts either a promise, either **a number in milliseconds**:

> `timeout` – `{number|Promise}` – *timeout in milliseconds, or promise that should abort the request when resolved.*

Therefore the solution is straightforward:

```
function getData () {
    return $http.get(someUrl, {timeout: 3000});  // adjust the value to what you need
}
```